# unexcpected token db in cloud function

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase cloud function and I want to send notification when a product is added in firebase DB. To do that, I am fetching device token from firestore. However, when I run **firebase deploy**, I get this error message:

> ```
>  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token db
> ```

**Here's the code in index.js**

```
/* eslint-disable */ 
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.sendToDevice = functions.database
  .ref('products/{productId}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
   // const product = snapshot.val();
   
    const querySnapshot = await db
      .collection('users')
      .doc('abcdefgh1235678')
      .collection('tokens')
      .get();

    const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.id);
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens,{ 
        notification: {
            title: 'New Product!',
            body: `New product is  ${context.params.productId}`,
            click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
          }
    });

    return;
});
```

I am getting the following error after updating my answer:

> error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

```
/* eslint-disable */ 
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();  
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.printitemcreated = functions.database.ref('/products/{productId}')
    .onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {
      const original = snapshot.val();     
      const querySnapshot = await db
            .collection('users')
            .doc('abcdefg123456')
            .collection('tokens')
            .get();
      
          const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.id);
          await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens,{ 
              notification: {
                  title: 'New Product!',
                  body: `New product is  ${context.params.productId}`,
                  click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
                }
          });
      return;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK `db` is not a reserved keyword for Cloud Functions.

The problem most probably comes from the fact that you don't [initialize an admin app instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app). You should do `admin.initializeApp();`.

In addition, your Cloud Function contains other (key) errors: you use `await` without declaring the handler as `async` and you don't await the call to `admin.messaging()`.

The following code should work:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(); // <- See here

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.sendToDevice = functions.database
  .ref('products/{productId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {    // <- See async here
   // const product = snapshot.val();
   
    const querySnapshot = await db
      .collection('users')
      .doc('abcdefgh1235678')
      .collection('tokens')
      .get();

    const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.id);
    await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens,{    // <- See await here
        notification: {
            title: 'New Product!',
            body: `New product is  ${context.params.productId}`,
            click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
          }
    });

    return null;    // <- See null here
});
```

Comment: After making suggested changes, I am now getting this error: Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you anymore.... The exact code in my answer deploys correctly in one of my test Firebase project.

Comment: See the change at the end: `return null;` instead of just `return;`